# How to convert a collection of strings to an array of individual strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {
  let newArr = []
  let userData = [data]
  return userData.forEach(data => {
    data.map(data => {
      let answer = (data[0] >= 55 && data[1] > 7) ? console.log("Senior") : console.log("Open");
      return answer
    })
  })
}
```

the above function should either display senior or open in this form `[ 'Open', 'Senior', 'Open', 'Senior' ]`
the outpout i got instead was:
Open
Senior
Open
Senior

an example of what is expected:

```
input = [[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]] 
output = ["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]
```

Comment: do you have some data and wanted result?

Comment: yes the output i got is : Open
Senior
Open
Senior

Comment: do you got it or do you want it? and what data do you take as input? how should we try a proposal?

Comment: the format of my output is the issue

Comment: remove the first 3 lines in the function, prepend return before data.map and remove inside curly and assignment, as well both `console.log` methods, keep the strings and close the mapping without curly. remove last line of function as well. voilà

Comment: omg thanks so much and to think i wrote all that

Comment: @EmmaMaina Why did you approve that destructive edit that was just an attempt at a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could just map the wanted strings, depending on the values of left an right items of the nested arrays.

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {
    return data.map(([l, r]) => l >= 55 && r > 7 ? 'Senior' : 'Open');
}

const data = [[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]];

console.log(openOrSenior(data)); // ["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the same code-template that you have provided in the description then you can solve it in this way:

```
function openOrSenior(data) {
  let newArr = []
  let userData = [data]
  userData.forEach(data => {
    data.map(dataInside => {
      let answer = (dataInside[0] >= 55 && dataInside[1] > 7) ? "Senior" : "Open"
      newArr.push(answer)
    })
  })
  return newArr
}

const data = [[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]];
console.log(openOrSenior(data)); // ["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]
```

But in above solution, we are performing redundant operations, the better way to solve it will be this one:

```
function openOrSenior(data) {  
    return data.map(dataInside => (dataInside[0] >= 55 && dataInside[1] > 7) ? "Senior" : "Open")     
}

const data = [[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]];
console.log(openOrSenior(data)); // ["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]
```